# How to add password connection string

Tags: connection-string

How to add password in below mentioned connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Gate_App.My.MySettings.GateDbConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GateDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=True "
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Gate_App.My.MySettings.GateDbConnectionString1" connectionString=" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GateDb.accdb;  User ID=*******; Password='*******';Persist Security Info=True "
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <add name="Gate_App.My.MySettings.GateDbConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GateDb.accdb;User Id=id;Password=pass;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Gate_App.My.MySettings.GateDbConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GateDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

[Access connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)